# SQL get only earlier date in repetitive rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have an SQL table contains transactions like this

```
ID | FK | STATUS | DATE

1  | A  | K1     | 2021-01-01
2  | A  | K1     | 2021-01-15
3  | A  | K2     | 2021-01-30
4  | A  | K2     | 2021-02-03
5  | B  | K1     | 2021-01-12
6  | C  | K1     | 2021-03-30
7  | C  | K3     | 2021-09-15
```

As we can see, some FK have some records with different STATUS and different DATE. From each FK I want to get the first/earlier transaction date with status K1.

Maybe something like this.

```
ID | FK | STATUS | DATE
1  | A  |   K1   | 2021-01-01
5  | B  |   K1   | 2021-01-12
6  | C  |   K1   | 2021-03-30
```

How can I get the result like that?

Note : I'm using MariaDB version 10.5.9-MariaDB

Comment: Your "and" in the English statement above is ambiguous. What do you mean by "transactions from each FK with status = K1 and earlier"?

Comment: Forgive me, I have edited the question..

Comment: @Iwan with the updated sample data shared, your expected result would also be updated. the ID 4 would change to 5 and the ID 5 would change to 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  `ID` INTEGER,
  `FK` VARCHAR(1),
  `STATUS` VARCHAR(2),
  `DATE` DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO my_table
  (`ID`, `FK`, `STATUS`, `DATE`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'A', 'K1', '2021-01-01'),
  ('2', 'A', 'K1', '2021-01-15'),
  ('3', 'A', 'K2', '2021-01-30'),
  ('4', 'A', 'K2', '2021-02-03'),
  ('5', 'B', 'K1', '2021-01-12'),
  ('6', 'C', 'K1', '2021-03-30'),
  ('7', 'C', 'K3', '2021-09-15');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    FK, 
    STATUS, 
    DATE 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        row_number() over (partition by FK,STATUS order by DATE ASC) rn from my_table 
) t
where STATUS='K1' and rn=1;
```

| ID | FK | STATUS | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | K1 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 5 | B | K1 | 2021-01-12 00:00:00 |
| 6 | C | K1 | 2021-03-30 00:00:00 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6u65bMuuwZNva1y8SWb6Q4/1)

Comment: Some FK have some records with same STATUS = K1 but different date. I'd like to get only K1 with earlier date

Comment: what if `K1` isn't first row for a FK on that date?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte_customers AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fk,status
             ORDER BY 
date
                
        ) row_num, 
        customer_id, 
        fk, 
        status
     FROM 
        sales.customers
) SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    cte_customers
WHERE 
    row_num =1;
```

Comment: This is a sql server query check if you are able to do something similar in Mariadb

Answer (score 0):

This is solved with a [windowing function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions/):

```
WITH RowNumbers AS (
    SELECT *, 
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY FK ORDER BY Date) As rn
    FROM [MyTable]
    WHERE Status = 'K1'
)
SELECT ID, FK, STATUS, DATE
FROM RowNumbers
WHERE rn = 1
```

Window functions were added to MariaDB in version 10.2. The CTE is also needed because row_number() isn't computed until *after* the WHERE clause is processed.